# How to avoid lines that contain both string and numbers before splitting them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, readlines

I use python 3, and I read files that strart with few lines that contain text and number together, and from a certain line it's only columns of numbers, that originally they are also read as str after splitting, that I later convert them to float.

the data look like this . I also add the link to the sample of the numbers

https://gist.github.com/Farzadtb/b0457223a26704093524e55d9b46b1a8

[image]

So the problem is that for reading I have two conditions ( actually I wish to increase these conditions ) using try: except . but this only works for dividing the splitting method. but before I start splitting ,I need to remove the first lines that contain text. what I know is that I should use

except ValueError

but this does not really work !

```
f = io.open(file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    #f=open(file,"r")
    lines=f.readlines()

    x=[]
    y=[]
    z=[]    

    for i in lines:

        try:
            a=[i.strip('\n')]
            a1=[float(n) for n in a[0].split(',')]
            atot.append(a1)
            x.append(a1[3])
            y.append(a1[2])
            z.append(a1[1])

        except :
             a=[i.split('\n')]
             a1=[float(n) for n in a[0].split()]
             x.append(a1[3])
             y.append(a1[2])
             z.append(a1[1])
```

the problem is that since the first lines could also start with numbers, it's possible that the first parameter is split and added to "x" and "y" but I get error for z

```
x=[float(i) for i in x]
y=[float(i) for i in y]
z=[float(i) for i in z]
```

One idea that comes to my mind is to check if the line could be converted to float with no errors , and then proceed with splitting ,but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data? Is there a constant number of lines at the beginning you want to skip?

Comment: I added an image of my data , it's the contrary, I want to avoid the first text lines

Comment: Don't you have constant number of headers or columns when it's numbers?

Comment: Above the numbers I have their titles, like x1(mm) ,etc. but above them in the beginning there are dispersed texts to avoid

Comment: I also offered my idea, that I don't know how to apply : to check if converting the line to float bumps error or not

Comment: There are string methods like `isalnum()`, `isalpha()`. They could be helpful.

Comment: But does isallnum() give True if io. open reads the lines with numbers as str?

Comment: the first line that starts with numbers is read as this :
 -3.1923      0.6784     -4.6481     -0.0048      0.3399     -0.2829      0.0000     24.0477\n'

Comment: So it gives False , as it is also str, like its above lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this. This code use regexp to find the data as a clean way.

```
import pprint
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pattern to ignore line containing alpha or :
    ignore_pattern = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z:]*[a-zA-Z:]')
    # number pattern
    number_pattern = re.compile(r'[-.\d]+')

    matrix = []

    # open the file as readonly
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file_:

        # iterator over lines
        for line in file_:
            # remove \n and spaces at start and end
            line = line.strip()
            if not ignore_pattern.match(line):

                found = number_pattern.findall(line)
                if found:
                    floats = [float(x) for x in found]
                    matrix.append(floats)

    # print matrix in pretty format
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
    pp.pprint(matrix)

    # access value by [row][column] starting at 0
    print(matrix[0][2])
```

Tested on your sample data.
This is the stdout of the python script:

```
[[-3.1923, 0.6784, -4.6481, -0.0048, 0.3399, -0.2829, 0.0, 24.0477],
 [-3.1827, 0.7048, -4.6257, 0.0017, 0.3435, -0.2855, 0.0, 24.0477],
 [-3.1713, 0.7237, -4.5907, 0.0094, 0.3395, -0.2834, 0.0, 24.0477]]
-4.6481
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what if the format is not txt ? it seems like it does not enter the loop

Comment: You just have to change the filename in the open statement. Could you provide your data in text format, not as an image?

Comment: yes , i would do that , but how to upload them here ?

Comment: Ok thank you I'll do it tomorrow, too late now for me

Comment: I added the numbers to gist.github and included the link in my question

Comment: I've seen the gist. There is more than 3 columns? What do you want to do with other columns? Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: You can use 5 columns or ignore them. The main objective is to ignore or remove the first rows until the numbers start

Comment: Solution updated with your data sample. Don't forget to accept the solution :-)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! Shall I ask you what does the 
if __name__ == '__main__': do?

Comment: You can remove it safely. This statement check if you're running the script instead of importing, as a module. I use to put it on top on my main function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Justin one more thing, I couldn't find something to understand what does the r'[^a-zA-Z:]*[a-zA-Z:]') do, could you give me some keywords?

Comment: It's a regexp. You should read this doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. This instruction find lines that have alpha or colon characters. So, if we find one, the line is ignored in the next if instruction. The r'[-.\d]+' is used to find numbers.